# ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: php, laravel-5, imagemagick, intervention

i have installed ImageMagick in my mac book by using home brew, when i search that imageMagick is available in my mac book, the below are search results screenshot.
[image]

i am using image intervention package when i store my picture in my server, getting error
code explain below

```
// Store a copy
    if($request->hasFile('profilepicture'))
    {
        $image_org = Image::make($request->file('profilepicture'))->encode('png');
        dd($image_org); // getting error
        try {
            // $image_org = Image::make($request->file('profilepicture'))->encode('png');
            // Storage::disk('ppics')->put($viewPortOrg, $image_org);
            Storage::disk('ppics')->put($viewPortOrg, $request->file('profilepicture'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::error($e);
            return redirect()->back()->with('error','Invalid image uploaded, please try a different image');
        }
    }
```

the Error screen shot is below
[image]

how i could resolve this error? Any help?

Comment: What is `Image::make`? That seems to be part of the nether the GD extension not the imagik extension for php. So what module _does_ provide that class?

Comment: Also please keep in mind that the usual ImageMagick solution does _not_ provide a php extension, that is a separate thing. And you also need to tell php to load such a module in the configuration of that specific version and flavor you currently use on your system.

Comment: If you want PHP with ImageMagick, you are looking for Imagick PHP API, which makes calls to ImageMagick.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: hi @arkascha how i could tell to php to load such module?

Comment: Well, open your systems software management system, search for it and click to install it.